# Ошибка:  'a' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, qt

Скачал последний qt 5.3.0 c MinGW 4.8.2 и удивился. (тоже самое и с qt 5.2.0 с MinGW 4.8.0)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Super{
    class A{
    protected:
        int a;
    };
    class B : public A{
        int b;
        B(){
            b = a;
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Не работает. Выдаёт:

```
C:\***\main.cpp:14: ошибка: 'a' was not declared in this scope
             b = a;
                 ^
```

Хотя, убрать строку `template <typename T>`, то всё работает.

Причём приведённый выше код без изменений работает, например, в Visual Studio 2008. Это баг MinGW или же это так и надо/допустимо? Кстати, нормально работает с MinGW и если писать `this->a`.

Comment: А зачем так делать? Почему бы не обращаться из класса B к protected-членам A через операцию ::? Например,
    
int B::showa() const
{
  return A::a;
}

Comment: @andrejap: насколько я понял, суть вопроса в том, а почему обязательно так?

Comment: @G0ohan: не работает даже если поменять `protected` на `public`.

Comment: @VladD: да, такая замена не поменяет ситуации. И вы верно проинтервьюировали вопрос.

Comment: проверил код на доступных gcc 4.4 - 4.9 и clang 3.0-3.3. Intel компилятор (icc) справился, но похоже он просто выбросил класс в процессе оптимизации.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Кажется, я понял. [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4011351/276994) обсуждают похожую проблему.

В вашем случае ситуация такова. `b` является *зависимым именем*. Компилятор должен понять значение этого зависимого имени *до* подстановки `T`. (Посмотрите детали и обсуждение в [этом вопросе](/questions/239051)). Поскольку он не может, разработчики стандарта решили убрать зависимые имена из области видимости внутри шаблона. Поэтому вам приходится указывать явно, что именно вам нужно.

Таким образом, баг в старом Visual Studio, их реализация не вполне соответствовала стандартам. (В новом Visual Studio уже соответствует.)

Я считаю, что язык C++ неоправданно избыточно сложен. Вы натолкнулись на одно из таких мест.

Comment: Ну тут теперь вопрос: кто же соответствует стандартам? Баг это или фича у VS? Проверил в 2012 студии, там, также как и в 2008, всё работает.

Comment: Хм, в 2012 работает? Насколько я понимаю, это обязан быть баг.

Comment: @VladD, нужно придумать пример, в котором VS сломается из-за этого бага. Иначе это не баг =)

Comment: А на мой взгляд это ошибка в GNU. 

Причем наведенная. 

Реально `T` вообще никак не используется в этой программе. 

Однако, вместо полезного (или бесполезного) warning-a компайлер ловит несуществующую ошибку (или следствие другой -- глобальной ошибки (внутренне противоречивый C++ и система стандартов)).

Comment: @avp: Причина этому такова: компилятор не может понять, к чему относится зависимое имя, во время чтения шаблона. То, что в данном случае `T` не используется, не играет роли, т. к. правило не может говорить «в случае, если могу разрешить ссылку, можно использовать, а если не могу, то нельзя».

Comment: @G0ohan: не следование стандарту и есть баг.

Comment: @VladD, но Вы согласны, что это ошибка в g++?

Хотя, мы просто не знаем с какими ключами компиляции @G0ohan запускал этот пример.

IMHO без ключей -- надо компилировать и писать warning (правда, какие идеи популярны в GNU Project сейчас я не знаю).

(кстати, в

g++.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3


g++ без всяких ключей -- тоже не компилирует. Ошибка).

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, gcc прав, т. к. он следует стандарту. `a` есть dependent name и не доступно в контексте, в котором оно используется.

Почему именно стандарт предписывает так — отдельная история. В [другом вопросе](/questions/239051/) есть обсуждение того, почему именно стандарт делает dependent names недоступными.

Answer (score 1):

При выполнении поиска неквалифицированных имен (unqualified name lookup), в рассмотрение не включаются базовые классы, зависящие от параметров текущего шаблона. В данном случае `A` - это на самом деле `Super<T>::A` и зависит от параметра шаблона `T`. По этой причине имя `a` из базового класса `A` не находится компилятором.

Использование квалифицированого имени или явного синтаксиса доступа к члену класса устранит ошибку

```
int b = A::a;
int b = this->a;
```

Это правило связанно с поиском неквалифицированных имен *именно в базовых классах*, а не с зависимыми именами вообще. Эта деталь почему-то не затронута в принятом ответе.